# Button onclick display href links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I have a problem that I cannot work out I have a HTML button code is below when I click this I want a java script function to run that will display links on the page and then when I press the second button I want a separate set of links to display any ideas how to do this all my HTML elements are within a

my HTML button is this i have put type on the button because it was acting like a submit button when it was within a form.

```
echo"<button type=\"button\" id=\"1\" onclick =\"display(firstbox)\">";
echo "Firstbox";
echo "</button>";
```

this is the div that everything is displayed within

```
echo "<div id=\"links\"> 
echo "</div>";
```

my JavaScript function is this

```
$("#1").click(function(){
$("#links").text("'<div id="id">' heeellllooooo '</div>'   ");
});
```

when I try this nothing is displayed when I get rid of the HTML elements it shows the hello is it because I have used .text do I need to change this to something else or is there a better way to do this using a different javascript or jquery functions or maybe css anything would be great

any ideas or help would be much appreciated i just cant seem to get this to work no matter what i try

in the end i would like these links within the section it says hello these are the links

```
<br/>
<br/>
<a href="./downloads/"> Guide to Producing a Video</a>
<br /><br />
<a href="./downloads/"> Guide to Producing a Academic Exercise</a>
<br /><br />
<a href="./downloads/"> Questionnaire</a>
<br /><br />
<a href="./downloads/"> Guide to Producing a Video</a>
<br /><br />
<a href="./downloads/"> Guide to Producing a Academic Exercise</a>
<br /><br />
<a href="./downloads/"> Questionnaire</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html/). `$.html()` treats the string as HTML, `$.text()` treats the content as text.Try this:

```
$("#1").click(function(){
$("#links").html("<div id=id>heeellllooooo</div>");
});
```

Comment: i have tried this previously and this did not work and i have just tried it incase you changed something and yours does not work

Comment: @user3387522: Issue might be with `id="id">'`. What is variable id here? From where we will get value?

Comment: the id="id" is just the id of the div that i would like posted to the screen that is all

Comment: @user3387522: If `id` is not a variale then try above code. It should work.

Comment: the `id` is not a variable

Comment: @user3387522: Check updated fiddle with missing code: http://jsfiddle.net/RnnpT/2/

Comment: i updated the code within the fiddle and it works but this is the code i have in my page with the div and this does not work

Answer (score 0):

problem in quotes and tag

```
$("#links").html("<div id='id'> heeellllooooo </div>");
```

if **id** is a javascript variable.

Comment: this didnt work and also the `id` is not a javascript variable it is the `<div>` id

Answer (score 0):

Try this,  [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/y4Nad/1/)

```
  $("#1").click(function(){
    $("#links").html('<div id="id">heeellllooooo</div>');
  });
```